# jquery: wrap all elements not each

Tags: jquery

i go threw some elements with same class with `each` function. but if i `wrap` them each element gets wrapped.

so HTML should look like

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="each"></div>
<div class="each"></div>
</div>
```

and not like

```
<div class="wrap"><div class="each"></div></div>
<div class="wrap"><div class="each"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [jQuery.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/).

Answer (score 0):

```
var collect_all_each = $('<div>',{'class': 'wrap'});
$('.each').each(function(){
    $(this).appendTo(collect_all_each);
});
```